# Bash script to remove two lines of text in an HTML file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

My goal is a script that downloads a webpage then uses regex to remove two lines from the HTML file.  I'm past the HTML downloading part but am having problems making the script play nice with the HTML file.

Running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3, I've found the following Grep command does remove the two lines of text in the HTML, but the icon of the HTML file does strange things and I don't trust it's doing what its supposed to.

Does this work in a bash script?  In my testing it does but I want to know if I can leave the script running without worrying about it.  -Thanks!

```
egrep -v 'String01|string02' new1.html > new.html
```

Comment: are two full lines ? Does the test only include the strings and not other HTML elements ?

Comment: Two separate lines and one line can be matched using ASCII text but the other has an HTML tag.  As usual things work great from BASH but once scripted I'm just not so sure.

Comment: If you need to remove the string but not the TAG, grep is not the right tool. `sed -e "s/String01//g" -e "s/String02//g"  new1.html > new.html` should work better.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the two lines matching the regex.  I tried using sed -i but the input file just "flashed" on the desktop during testing and the script fails.

Comment: It will work, no problem...

Comment: @Jahid what would?  The `sed` commands or the `egrep` script?